# Use masking with LSTM layer, in many-to-many problem

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I'm trying to create a model that inputs sequence of integers (indexes) and outputs another sequence of integers (indexes). These indexes are encoded item_ids. As I have timesteps with different lengths, I right padded all the sequences and now I'm adding a `Masking` before the `LSTM` layer. So after padding, all the sequences has `18` length, and I want to output sequences of `18` length too, but something is not wrong with my dimensions. Also I have only 1 feature.

I'm pretty new to neural networks, so forgive some mistake.

```
model = Sequential()

# masking empty timesteps
model.add(Masking(mask_value=MASKING, input_shape=(timesteps, 1)))

# LSTM layer with "max_views" time steps and one feature
model.add(LSTM(50)) # I tried to do model.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(timesteps, 1))) but it gives the same result

# we need to output max views labels
model.add(Dense(timesteps))

# we can use here sparse categorical crossentropy, because our data are integers
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Also I'm using `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` as my data are integers, not hot encoded.
This is the summary:

```
Model: "sequential_43"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
masking_35 (Masking)         (None, 18, 1)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_42 (LSTM)               (None, 50)                10400     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_30 (Dense)             (None, 18)                918       
=================================================================
Total params: 11,318
Trainable params: 11,318
Non-trainable params: 0
```

When I try to fit the model:

```
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=1, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), verbose=1)
```

It gives me the error:

```
ValueError: Shape mismatch: The shape of labels (received (18,)) should equal the shape of logits except for the last dimension (received (1, 18)).
```

These are my 3D array shapes:

```
print(X_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(X_val.shape)
print(y_val.shape)
(117182, 18, 1)
(117182, 18, 1)
(4132, 18, 1)
(4132, 18, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the shape of y_train is not proper.

How about trying this:

y_train = y_train.reshape(y_train.shape[:-1])

to reduce y_train's shape as (117182, 18).